# Why $GL_n(F)$ Is Not Abelian?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I know that $GL_n(F)$ is not abelian for $n\geq 2$. But I may be missing out something. By definition a matrix  $A$ is invertible iff there is $A^{-1}$ s.t $A\cdot A^{-1}=A^{-1}\cdot A=I$. So  if we take a matrix $A\in GL_n(F)$, from the definition of invertible, the operation is commutative.

Comment: It's not Abelian for $n=2$ also!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown it's true no matter $F$ ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ok I will edtied

Comment: It's non-Abelian since there are elements $A$, $B$ with $AB\ne BA$. I can't see what you are asking here.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $GL_n{F}$ is a set of invertible matrices so if $A\in GL_n{F} $ So there is $A^{-1}$ s.t $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ as the definition of invertible matrix

Comment: Commutativity has nothing to do with invertibility! An invertible matrix always commutes with its inverse, but there are many other matrices it may *not* commute with.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff that what I was missing we need that for all $A,B\in Gl_n(F)$ we will have $AB=BA=I$ and not just $A^{-1}$, Thanks!!!

Comment: @GabrielRomon If you take two fairly "random" matrices they almost certainly won't commute. When I say random here, I mean avoid daft things like one being a scalar matrix or a multiple of another matrix etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why $GL_n(F)$ Is Not Abelian?

Because you can find invertible linear transformation that don't commute.

For example with $n=2$:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

You can easily make this work for arbitrary $n$ using the same trick.